# Is it possible to make Head JS's ready() function wait for two scripts?

Tags: javascript, head.js

I load three scripts on my webpage, and I would like to trigger a function once two of them has finished loading.

```
 head.js(
     { webfont: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.0.31/webfont.js' },
     { jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js' },
     { analytics: 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js' }
 );
```

Ideally I would like to be able to do the following, but it does not seem possible to make head.ready() wait for two scripts to load, according to the [documentation](http://headjs.com/#usage) (see Script Organization).

```
head.ready('jquery', function() {
    // Code that requires jQuery.
});

// This is not supported. :-(
head.ready('jquery', 'analytics', function() {
    // Code that requires both jQuery and Google Analytics.
    // ...
});
```

So how should I solve this? If I nest the ready methods, can I be sure that my code will be triggered, or will it only be triggered if jquery finishes loading before analytics?

```
head.ready('jquery', function() {
   // Code that requires jQuery.
   // ...
   head.ready('analytics', function() {
       // Code that requires both jQuery and Google Analytics.
       // ...
   });
});
```

Another solution could be to break up the loading statements into two parts, like this. But will I still benefit fully from the asynchroneous loading of the scripts, or will it finish loading webfont before jquery and analytics?

```
 head.js(
     { webfont: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.0.31/webfont.js' }
 );

 head.js(
     { jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js' },
     { analytics: 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js' },
     function() {
         // Code that requires both jQuery and Google Analytics.
         // ...
     }
 );

 head.ready('jquery', function() {
     // Code that requires jQuery.
     // ...
 });
```

Comment: I don't know about HeadJS, but I expect such techniques to handle nested calls perfectly fine. Similarly in Java `Process.join()` on multiple processes is simply called one-after-the-other, because even if the order of process completion is different from the order of `join()` calls, previously-completed processes will simply cause `join` to return immediately. I expect a `ready()` call for an already-loaded library to simply call the callback immediately (or on the next tick).

Comment: They documentation and home page show several clear examples of waiting for multiple scripts to load. What are you seeing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since scripts are executed in order (even though loaded in parallel), you can wait for the script that was "last-in-line"

```
head.js(
    { webfont  : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.0.31/webfont.js' },
    { jquery   : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js' },
    { analytics: 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js' }
);

 head.ready('analytics', function() {
    // when this triggers, webfont & jquery will have finished loading too
 });
```

Comment: You caught the words extremely correct: "They load in parallel but execute in order". +1 for you.